# Is there any way to add a "dropdown menu on hover" on nav list items?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have a navigation and I would like to add a dropdown menu (on hover) on two of my navigation list items (on the first two on the left side). What's the best way to possibly do this? I tried some solutions from Google but none really worked for me it just messed up my navigation.

Here's my Navigation: 
(expand to full page to see the nav working)

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

html {
  font-family: "Roboto", serif;
}

.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  height: 180px;
  font-family: "Roboto", serif;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 99999;
  background-color: rgba(175, 213, 123, 0.70);
}

.navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navigation ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #222222;
  margin: -12px 0;
  letter-spacing: 0.200em;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.navigation ul li:hover {
  color: #ffa947;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 770px) {
  .navigation ul li {
    margin: 17px 0;
  }
}

.navigation ul li.reg {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-size: 0.625rem;
}

@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 770px) {
  .navigation ul li.reg {
    display: none;
  }
}

.navigation ul li.title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.navigation h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #222222;
  font-weight: 300;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 770px) {
  .navigation {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: auto;
  }
}

.navigation.sticky {
  height: 55px;
  background-color: rgba(175, 213, 123, 1);
}

.navigation.sticky::after {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.navigation.sticky ul li {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 770px) {
  .navigation.sticky {
    height: auto;
  }
  .navigation.sticky .title {
    margin: 17px 0;
  }
}

.navigation .hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 770px) {
  .navigation .hidden {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
  }
  .navigation .hidden li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    transition: all 0s;
  }
}

.navigation .hidth {
  display: none;
}

.navigation .switch .hidth {
  display: block;
}

.navigation .switch .unhid {
  display: none;
}

.navigation .hidden.showmenu {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 770px) {
  .navigation .hidden.showmenu {
    visibility: visible;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
  }
  .navigation .hidden.showmenu li {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    transition: all 0s;
  }
  .navigation .hidden.showmenu li:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
}

.navigation .bar {
  display: none;
  margin: 17px 0;
  font-size: 21px;
}

@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 770px) {
  .navigation .bar {
    display: block;
  }
}

.navigation .bar:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="reg goHome">Kleingartenverein</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="reg goug">UrbanGardening</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="title gotop">GARDEN7</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="reg goGalerie">Galerie</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="reg goKontakt">Kontakt</li>
    </a>
    <span class="bar">
            <i class="fa fa-bars unhid" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
            <i class="fa fa-times hidth" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
  </ul>
  <ul class="hidden">
    <a href="#">
      <li class="goHomemob">Kleingartenverein</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="goKleingartenvereinmob">Urban Gardening</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="goGaleriemob">Galerie</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li class="goKontaktmob">Kontakt</li>
    </a>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid to start with. You cannot wrap `li` in links. `li` **must** be direct children of  `ul` and **only** `li`.

Comment: But how is that a problem? This doesnt change anything does it?

Comment: Here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100344/pure-css-multi-level-drop-down-menu

Comment: ..and yes it does mess up. It's invalid HTML and can cause browsers not to understand your code. **When in doubt, *validate*.**

Comment: [W3 has a great example for hover dropdowns](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp)

Comment: @Robofan i have tried the ones on w3 and they did not work for me

Comment: @Paulie_D Okay thanks a lot ! I´ll try the one you send. The problem i had with switching a and li so the li´s are the direkt children of ul - messed up my nav

Comment: @Paulie_D so i have tried it with my nav - did not work like expected and i also tried to switch so the li is the direct children and it just messed up everything. Could you try do solve this or help me more? Thanks.

Comment: im trying 30minutes no and nothing works :S

Comment: @Robofan The name of the site is W3Schools. [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/) is the site for the World Wide Web Consortium (aka w3c), which actually maintains the standards (and has no ads).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create submenu with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419345/create-submenu-with-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

html {
  font-family: "Roboto", serif;
}

.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  height: 180px;
  font-family: "Roboto", serif;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 99999;
  background-color: rgba(175, 213, 123, 0.70);
}

.navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navigation ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #222222;
  margin: -12px 0;
  letter-spacing: 0.200em;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  position:relative;
}
.navigation ul li a{
  font-size: 0.625rem;
  text-decoration: none;
   color: #222222;
}
.navigation ul li a:hover{
  color: #ffa947;
}
.navigation ul li .submenu{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  top:15px;
  left:0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px #e8e8e8 solid;
  
}
.navigation ul li:hover .submenu{
  display: block;
}
.navigation ul li .submenu li{
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px #e8e8e8 solid;
}
.navigation ul li .submenu li a{
  color: #ffa947;
}
.navigation ul li:hover {
  color: #ffa947;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 770px) {
  .navigation ul li {
    margin: 17px 0;
  }
}

.navigation ul li.reg {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-size: 0.625rem;
}

@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 770px) {
  .navigation ul li.reg {
    display: none;
  }
}

.navigation ul li.title a{
  font-size: 24px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.navigation h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #222222;
  font-weight: 300;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 770px) {
  .navigation {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: auto;
  }
}

.navigation.sticky {
  height: 55px;
  background-color: rgba(175, 213, 123, 1);
}

.navigation.sticky::after {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.navigation.sticky ul li {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 770px) {
  .navigation.sticky {
    height: auto;
  }
  .navigation.sticky .title {
    margin: 17px 0;
  }
}

.navigation .hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 770px) {
  .navigation .hidden {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
  }
  .navigation .hidden li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    transition: all 0s;
  }
}

.navigation .hidth {
  display: none;
}

.navigation .switch .hidth {
  display: block;
}

.navigation .switch .unhid {
  display: none;
}

.navigation .hidden.showmenu {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 770px) {
  .navigation .hidden.showmenu {
    visibility: visible;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
  }
  .navigation .hidden.showmenu li {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    transition: all 0s;
  }
  .navigation .hidden.showmenu li:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
}

.navigation .bar {
  display: none;
  margin: 17px 0;
  font-size: 21px;
}

@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 770px) {
  .navigation .bar {
    display: block;
  }
}

.navigation .bar:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul>
   
      <li class="reg goHome"> <a href="#">Kleingartenverein</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Demo Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Demo Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Demo Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    
    
      <li class="reg goug"><a href="#">UrbanGardening </a>
        <ul class="submenu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Demo Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Demo Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Demo Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
   
    
      <li class="title gotop"><a href="#">GARDEN7</a></li>
    
    
      <li class="reg goGalerie"><a href="#">Galerie</a></li>
    
    
      <li class="reg goKontakt"><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    
    <span class="bar">
            <i class="fa fa-bars unhid" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
            <i class="fa fa-times hidth" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
  </ul>
  <ul class="hidden">
    
      <li class="goHomemob"><a href="#">Kleingartenverein</a></li>
    
    
      <li class="goKleingartenvereinmob"><a href="#">Urban Gardening </a></li>
   
    
      <li class="goGaleriemob"><a href="#">Galerie</a></li>
    
    
      <li class="goKontaktmob"><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Hey ! Yes thats perfect but now the Navigation is kind of messed up and that happend to me too ! it should stay the same as mine just if i hover over "Kleingarten" or "Urban Gardening" a menu should popup.

Comment: Yes Timur, please check now

Comment: Yes more like this ! But you see now if you open my version again. the garden7 is also orange and isnt bigger than the other items .. and it is not centered anymore

Comment: Okay Timur, give me minute to fix this.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, Please check now, you want like this or wanted any changes in this?

Comment: Please add explanation of the changes you made and (preferably) why.

Comment: Hi Heretic, Thanks for the advice but he asked to do the changes as I want to like this, that's why I did some changes. if you need an explanation then I can explain to you.

Comment: @jituthakur did you update the code snippet? looks the same as before for me.

Comment: No Timur, its little confusion if you look top one then you can see the update.

Comment: It is perfect ! The only thing thats "wrong" the whole items are not in the center of the website .. they are a bit to the right

Comment: Sorry, I have repeated the code but now I edited the code so you can check now. sorry for the confusion. Thanks

Comment: The item is the same as in your HTML but I can move in the left. give me a minute.

Comment: if you want the GARDEN7 in the center then you can add "width: 116px" in ".navigation ul li" class but there will be a more gap in "Galerie" and 'kontakt'. you apply the CSS and check.

Comment: Always, happy to help and please upvote the answer :)